# Laravel Storage Error: failed to open stream: Too many open files on a single, large file

Tags: amazon-s3, laravel-5.6

I'm using the Laravel Storage Implementation to copy files to Amazon S3.

```
Storage::disk('s3')->putFileAs($destinationPath, new File($filePath), $fileName);
```

While this works for files up to 1.2GB, it fails with larger files (1.7GB) with the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ErrorException: fopen(php://stderr): failed to open stream: operation failed in vendor/    symfony/console/Output/ConsoleOutput.php:150
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'fopen(php://std...', '/    ...', 150, Array)
#1 vendor/symfony/console/Output/ConsoleOutput.php(150): fopen('php://stderr', 'w')
#2 vendor/symfony/console/Output/ConsoleOutput.php(44): Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput->    openErrorStream()
#3 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(101):     Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput->__construct()
#4 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(87):     Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->renderForConsole(Object(RuntimeException))
#5 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->hand in vendor/symfony/console/Output/    ConsoleOutput.php on line 150
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ErrorException: include(vendor/symfony/debug/Exception/FatalErrorException.php): failed to     open stream: Too many open files in vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:444
Stack trace:
#0 vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(444): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'include(/    ...', '...', 444, Array)
#1 vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(444): include()
#2 vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(322): Composer\Autoload\includeFile('...')
#3 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('Symfony\\Compone...')
#4 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(136):     spl_autoload_call('Symfony\\Compone...')
#5 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(123):     Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->fatalExceptionFromError(A in vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on     line 444
```

The error seems strange, since I'm only uploading one file at a time.

Also to mention:

```
Storage::putFileAs($destinationPath, new File($filePath), $fileName);
```

This works, even with larger files (local copy).

Comment: Is there a way to use file handlers or streams?

Comment: I tried `Storage::disk('s3')->put($destinationPath.'/'.$fileName, fopen($completePath, 'r+'));` but that results in the same error...

Answer (score 0):

AWS multi-part uploading is pretty straight forward.

Start by installing the sdk:

```
composer require aws/aws-sdk-php
```

Add your AWS credentials to the `.env` file:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
```

Set up an S3 bucket and upload large files:

```
use Aws\S3\MultipartUploader; 
use Aws\Exception\MultipartUploadException;

$uploader = new MultipartUploader($s3Client, '/path/to/large/file.zip', [
     'bucket' => 'your-bucket',
     'key' => 'my-file.zip',
 ]); 

try {
    $result = $uploader->upload(); 
    echo "Upload complete: {$result['ObjectURL']}\n"; 
} catch (MultipartUploadException $e) { 
    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}
```

[Documentation here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/service/s3-multipart-upload.html)

Comment: I tried that as well, still receiving an error: `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ErrorException: fopen(php://stderr): failed to open stream: operation failed`.